# snapshot version not published after upgrading maven-release-plugin to 2.5.2

Tags: maven, publish, snapshot

Snapshot version is not published on snapshot repository but release version is published instead.

Release is successful. No errors.

Only change is upgrade of release plugin from 2.3.2 to 2.5.2

Also tried 2.5.1 and 2.5.3 but none worked.

Using apache maven 3.5.0

Steps:

- mvn clean install
- mvn release:prepare
- mvn release:perform

Output: Build Success in all three

Not sure if I can attach actual logs

snippet pom.xml

```
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
<artifactId>maven-overview-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
 <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
<artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <scmCommentPrefix>: Release by maven </scmCommentPrefix>
                        <tagNameFormat>bcd-@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                        <arguments>-Denvironment=target</arguments>
                    </configuration>

<repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>arm</id>
            <name>Internal release Repository</name>
            <url>url1</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>arm</id>
            <name>Internal Repository</name>
            <url>url2</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
```

Comment: Which Maven phases did you call? Which output did you get?

Comment: I did: 1)maven clean install 2) maven release:prepare 3) maven release:perform

Comment: Please edit the question, add the phases/Goals and the Output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by issue [MRELEASE-812](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-812) in the Maven Release plugin affecting 2.3.2 and solved since 2.5. However, *the plugin is actually supposed to publish the Release version  of your app*, not the Snapshot version. When you say:

> Snapshot version is not published on snapshot repository but release
>   version is published instead.

Snapshot version is not supposed to be published on repository when using the Release plugin. Publication of the release version is actually expected. Detailed explanation below.

What should happen when you use `mvn release:prepare release:perform`:

1. `release:prepare` will update your project from version `x.y.z-SNAPSHOT` to `x.y.z` (the "release" version of your project) commit+push all changes into your Git repository (or any other SCM) and create a tag named `bcd-x.y.z`
2. `release:perform` will checkout/pull from the tagged release `bcd-x.y.z` release and deploy it on your repository
3. The release version `x.y.z` is now deployed on your Repo.

This is actually what happened when you used version 2.5.2 of the Release plugin, **and is actually the expected and normal behavior.**

Here is what happened when you used version 2.3.2 of the plugin:

1. `release:prepare` updated your project from version x.y.z-SNAPSHOT to x.y.z, the "release" version of your project, **however** the changes never got pushed to Git due to [MRELEASE-812](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-812). A tagged thus got created using the `x.y.z-SNAPSHOT` version of your project instead of the proper release version because the changes updating your version number never got pushed.
2. `release:perform` will checked out the *improperly named * tag `bcd-x.y.z` actually containing the `x.y.z-SNAPSHOT` version and deployed it on your repository as a SNAPSHOT.
3. The snapshot version `x.y.z-SNAPSHOT` was now available on your repo.

Maven never shown any error but this is not proper behavior. Your real issue was actually with your previous usage of the Plugin, and your build is now having the expected behavior ;)

What you can do:

- I recommend you keep your actual configuration with the recent Plugin version. Keep in mind that the Maven Release Plugin is to publish *releases* of your app, not snapshots.
- If you want to publish SNAPSHOT versions to your repository, use `mvn deploy` on a revision containing a SNAPSHOT version instead of creating a release.

Hope this helps. Do not hesitate to ask details I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected as per the command/goals you are using:

- `mvn clean install` installs your SNAPSHOT dependency on your local repository but *it DOES NOT deploy it on your Maven repository*
- `mvn release:prepare` update your POMs for a release version and update your SCM with tag
- `mvn release:perform` actually deploys your release on repository

Your SNAPSHOT nevers get deployed on any repository. To achieve this, you should run the `deploy:deploy` goal before using the `release:*` goals. For example:

```
mvn clean install deploy:deploy release:prepare release:perform
```

Equivalent to:

```
mvn clean deploy release:prepare release:perform
```

Note that your pom.xml and repository should be properly configured to allow the deployment of SNAPSHOT artifacts.

Comment: when I use maven release plugin 2.3.2 version , I can publish snapshot in snapshot repo but nothing is published in release repo.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: There is 1 diff in the logs of 2 versions. I can see : scmCommentPrefix = Release by maven and push changes = true in version 2.3.2 . There is no such info in version 2.5.2.

Comment: I don"t think that's causing the issue. Please provide your pom.xml in your question. You run EXACTLY the same command using both versions of the plugin? How did you publish your snapshot using the 2.5.2?

Comment: yes , I run exactly same commands in both versions of plugin.

Comment: Pls let me know tags you want to have info about.  Added some info in the question.

Comment: Can you please include your entire pom.xml and build logs for both version's run? That'd help diagnose your issue.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your email where I can send the files?

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/78d81f2005d16d14af04e1ff87e96ea720171106082811/b3cdc6

Comment: Can't you copy-paste them directly on your question? If not use a service such as https://pastebin.com

Comment: These files contain logs upon execution of maven commands. Name indicates the release plugin version.

Comment: Thanks for the details. It is indeed a different issue than the one I talked about earlier, maybe combined with a misinterpretation of what the Release Plugin should do. I'll post another detailed answer in a few moments.